# Extracting a group from matched String in Java using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of String containing values like this:

```
String [] arr = {"${US.IDX_CA}", "${UK.IDX_IO}", "${NZ.IDX_BO}", "${JP.IDX_TK}", "${US.IDX_MT}", "more-elements-with-completely-different-patterns-which-is-irrelevant"};
```

I'm trying to extract all the  IDX_XX from this list. So from above list, i should have, IDX_CA, IDX_IO, IDX_BO etc using regex in Java

I wrote following code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)IDX_(\\w{2})");
for (String s : arr){
     Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
      if (m.matches()){
        String extract = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(extract);
      }
}
```

But this does not print anything. Can someone please tell me what mistake am i making. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following fix:

```
String [] arr = {"${US.IDX_CA}", "${UK.IDX_IO}", "${NZ.IDX_BO}", "${JP.IDX_TK}", "${US.IDX_MT}", "more-elements-with-completely-different-patterns-which-is-irrelevant"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bIDX_(\\w{2})\\b");
for (String s : arr){
     Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
      while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(0)); // Get the whole match
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // Get the 2 chars after IDX_
      }
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/1KzAmJ), output:

```
IDX_CA
CA
IDX_IO
IO
IDX_BO
BO
IDX_TK
TK
IDX_MT
MT
```

**NOTES**:

- Use `\bIDX_(\w{2})\b` pattern that matches `IDX_` and 2 word chars in between word boundaries and captures the 2 chars after `IDX_` into Group 1
- `m.matches` needs a full string match, so it is replaced with `m.find()`
- `if` replaced with `while` in case there are more than 1 match in a string
- `m.group(0)` contains the whole match values
- `m.group(1)` contains the Group 1 values.

Comment: Thank you, it works. May i ask, if i only want to extract the 2 chars after IDX_, how can i do it (without using String.split on the current return value) ?

Comment: @Adhyatmik Then use `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bIDX_(\\w{2})\\b");` and `System.out.println(m.group(1));`